# ASP .NET Core 3.1 Login constructor returns NULL. The Login properties are not binded from the Post request by JsonApiDotNetCore

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, json-api, asp.net-core-3.1

I am currently upgrading an ASP .NET Core Web API from 2.2 to 3.1. I am testing the controllers through PostMan to make sure everything is OK. It is not. When I first try to login, I send a valid username and password in the HttpPost request via Postman to the web API. However, when it calls the login constructor, it returns NULL, which means that the model does not contain the username and password that I just passed. Does anyone know why this is happening?

Note 1: I am confident that the Post request that I am submitting through PostMan is correct because I can successfully submit the same request to the .NET Core 2.2 web API.

Note 2: The WebApi is running .NET Core 3.1 with `JsonApiDotNetCore` 4.0.0-alpha4 whereas the model is contained in a separate .NET Standard 2.1 project with `JsonApiDotNetCore` 3.1 (I cannot upgrade to 4.0.0-alpha4 because it does not support .NET Standard 2.1). Could this be causing it?

**Login Controller**

```
using Test_Model.Users;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Test_WebApi.Controllers.Tokens
{
    public class TokensController : ControllerBase
    {
        public TokensController(
            IConfiguration objConfig,
            ILogger<TokensController> objLogger,
            IServiceProvider objServiceProvider)
            : base(objConfig, objLogger, objServiceProvider)
        { }

        [AllowAnonymous]
        [HttpPost("/clients/login")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> LoginAsync([FromBody] Login objLogin)
        {
            return new JsonResult(objLogin);
        }
    }
}
```

**Login Model**

```
using JsonApiDotNetCore.Models;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

public class Login
{
    // Constructor
    public Login() { } // When I place a breakpoint here, the debugger returns a NULL model in 3.1 but returns the model with the correct values from PostMan.

    // Properties
    [Required]
    [EmailAddress]
    [Attr("username")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Attr("password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Attr("rememberme")]
    public bool RememberMe { get; set; }
}
```

the jsonapidotnet is not populating the properties.

**Update**

Postman post request:

```
{
    username: "test@test.com",
    password: "12345",
    rememberme: "false"
}
```

Postman post settings:

```
Body = Raw
```

Headers (Key / Value):

```
Accept / application/json
Content-Type / application/json
```

Comment: Could you please show the request sent by PostMan?

Comment: @itminus Posted update.

Comment: I created a model Lib (targeting .NET Standard using JsonApiDotNetCore 3.1) and also another web project which uses JsonApiDotNetCore 4.0.0-alpha4 . However, your payload works fine for me. Is there a demo that reproduces the same issue?

Comment: @itminus Not handy - its a large project. Can you please post the model that you created so I can take a look at it? I imagine yours is smaller.

Comment: Sure, see this [sample](https://github.com/newbienewbie/SO60357476)

Comment: @itminus Ok, I stripped out the relevant code for the controller and pasted that. There are differences: You added `Person` to the model and changed the controlled to extend from `JsonApiController<Person>` instead of `ControllerBase`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208462/discussion-between-j-weezy-and-itminus).

Comment: @itminus It appears that you found the problem in that .NET Core 3.1 no longer allows a previously valid formatting of JSON that .NET Core 2.2 allowed. If you post the answer, I will accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. As of 3.0, ASP.NET Core uses `System.Text.Json` as the default JSON Serializer/Deserializer, which requires a strict JSON syntax. This behavior is different from the old Newtonsoft.JSON.
2. Actually, even the payload is supported by Newtonsoft.JSON, it is not a valid `JSON`:

   ```
   {
       username: "test@test.com",
       password: "12345",
       rememberme: "false"
   }
   ```

   (A JSON property should be a string that starts with `"`, see [JSON.org](https://www.json.org/json-en.html):

   [image: object]

   [image: string]
3. If you want to use JSON like what we did in old days, follow this [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#newtonsoftjson-jsonnet-support):

   - add a package reference to [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson)
   - add newtonsoft json options by `services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson(...);`

Comment: Thank you for explaining. I will be migrating away from `NewtonSoftJson` to `System.Text.Json`

Comment: this is the answer very helpful .. i search for days. Its really help, I also facing same issue when upgrade 2.1 to 3.1